# Dynamic Filtering in Power BI

Tags: javascript, c#, powerbi

I have embedded a power bi report into webpage. I have a table named 'Query1' in report where I have StudentId column whose datatype is text. I want to render the report on webpage by passing a specific StudentId into it.

For this, I have tried the below code:-

```
@model PowerBIEmbedded_AppOwnsData.Models.EmbedConfig

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="~/scripts/powerbi.js"></script>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ErrorMessage))
{
    <div id="errorWrapper">
        <h2>
            Error
        </h2>
        @Model.ErrorMessage
    </div>

    return;
}

<div id="reportContainer"></div>

@Html.Partial("LiveDemoLink")

<script>
    var accessToken = "@Model.EmbedToken.Token";

    // Read embed URL from Model
    var embedUrl = "@Html.Raw(Model.EmbedUrl)";

    var embedReportId = "@Model.Id";

    var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

    const filter = {
        $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
        target: {
            table: "Query1",
            column: "StudentId"
        },
        operator: "In",
        values: ["1524"]
    };
    var config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        id: embedReportId,
        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    };

    var reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];

    var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);

    if (report) {
        report.setFilters([filter])
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(function (errors) {
                console.log(errors);
            });
    }
</script>
```

But, dynamic filtering is not working out, I have set StudentId in Report Filters also.

I tried changing its datatype to whole number but it is not working.
What to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass the filter in the load config itself to avoid the setFilters() later.
2. if you're not sure the filter format is correct, I can advise a quick way to take care of this:

   - Set a filter you'd like with the filter pane (as in Power BI itself).
   - Call report.getFilters() and see how the JSON returned is different from yours.
   - All's left to do is modify the ID as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good but you missed the step: like report.off("loaded"). 
Below is typescript code you can change it to js :

```
report.off("loaded");
report.on("loaded", e =>{
            console.log("loaded");
            this.report.setFilters(filters)
            .then(filters=>{
                console.log("filters:" + filters);
            });
            this.report.off("error");
        } );
```

Happy Coding